# Постановка запятой при разных наклонениях глагола

Tags: пунктуация, глаголы, союзы, ссп, наклонение

*Вот мы **пришли** к ней и **видим**: она сидит на диване.* — ставится ли знак препинания перед союзом *И*?

Такой вопрос не так давно был задан участником форума. Ответ был таков: *Это однородные сказуемые, связанные одиночным союзом И, запятая не нужна.*

> § 30. *Оглянитесь вокруг, и увидите столько нового и интересного* (Газ.) —
>   сложносочиненное предложение (глагольные формы разных наклонений не
>   выступают в роли однородных членов простого предложения)

То есть **единственная** причина постановки запятой — наклонение глагола? Ни время, ни вид глагола, ни вопрос — ничто из этого никак не влияет на запятую?

Скажем, вместо глагола *пришли*, мы написали глагол в условном наклонении *пришли бы* (а вместо *видели* - *увидели*), в таком случае запятая была бы необходима?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Запятая не ставится, так как это однородные сказуемые, соединенные союзом *и*:

> Вот мы пришли к ней и видим: она сидит на диване.

2. Действительно, есть такой «пунктуационный нюанс»: если два глагола, относящиеся к одному и тому же субъекту, в **односоставном** предложении стоят в разных наклонениях, то они не являются однородными членами и между ними ставится запятая.

> Вот мы пришли бы к ней и увидели: она сидит на диване.

Здесь два глагола, употребленные в условном наклонении, а также двусоставное предложение  — запятая не ставится, см. пп. 1 и 2. Дело в том, что внешняя форма глагола *увидели* обманчива, нужно смотреть на то, какую ситуацию он описывает (а она ирреальная); также можно домыслить, что при нем опущена частица *бы*, хотя этот способ представляется менее действенным.

На однородность сказуемых не влияет:

- время: «Вася встал **(пр. вр)** и стоит **(н. вр.)**»;
- вид: «Он выпил **(сов. в.)** пива и играет **(несов. в.)** в карты».

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70724/discussion-on-answer-by-aer------).

Answer (score 4):

1) **Вот мы пришли к ней и видим**...

Это **двусоставное** предложение, поэтому сказуемые считаются однородными в любом случае.

2) **Оглянитесь вокруг, и увидите столько нового и интересного.**

Это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из двух **односоставных (определенно-личных) предложений** с разной формой сказуемого (разное наклонение).

ПАС под ред. Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой **безличные или неопределенно-личные предложения** с одинаковой формой сказуемого: С деревьев капало и вокруг пахло листвой; Зрителей разместили вокруг арены и на арену вывели участников представления;

3) **В общем случае** (по материалам учебников):

Запятая не ставится, если односоставные предложения **однородны**.

Для каждого вида односоставных предложений указываются признаки однородности. В частности, **определённо личные предложения являются однородными, если они выражены ОДНОЙ ФОРМОЙ ГЛАГОЛА и обозначают ОДНОГО ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЯ.**

Однородные предложения соединяются союзом И  одну фразу и читаются без паузы.

Форма глагола, судя по примерам, определяется наклонением.

**Примеры:**

Но здесь с победою поздравим Татьяну милую мою   и в сторону свой путь направим. Выходи, сударь, поскорее да обогрейся. Собираюсь выехать завтра и приеду к вечеру.

Оденься потеплее,  и пойдем гулять. Разные производители действия.

Выезжай завтра, и утром будешь на месте. Разные формы.