# Нужна ли запятая в моем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Пройди лабиринт, и узнаешь» нужна запятая?

Comment: Да, нужна. Запятая не ставится, когда оба предложения, соединенные сложносочинённой связью, являются повелительными.

Comment: Я исправила. Там без «ты». Все равно нужна?

Comment: Сказуемые не однородны, запятая нужна. См. [этот ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436249/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0/436252#436252).

Comment: Пройди и узнай. / Пройди, и узнаешь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Постановка запятой при разных наклонениях глагола](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436249/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)